# train_test_split : stratify can not be recognized?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to set `stratify = True`, but somehow jupyter notebook says 'name 'y' is not defined'

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    loan.drop('Loan_Status', axis=1), 
    loan['Loan_Status'], test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=y)
```

Can anyone tell me what is the proper way to do it?

I'm using Scikit-learn v0.19.1 and have tried to set `stratify = True / y / 2` but none of them worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass an **array** containing the class-labels (or whatever the criterion for stratifying is) as an argument to `stratify`.

In your case, the answer is probably `loan['Loan_Status'].values`.

Comment: It works! and I have understood the problem! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to stratify needs to be defined, ie, `y` has to be defined first.

```
X = loan.drop('Loan_Status', axis=1)
y = loan['Loan_Status']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=y)
```